# How to make a combination for strings?

Tags: python

how can I get a list output of combination of `a,b,c` like :

```
[(), ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('ab'), ('ac'), ('bc'), ('abc')]
```

Can you please share me sample code or a URL which already explained it, thanks

I should say I don't want it to be like:

```
[(), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Comment: Do you want the output to be a list of tuples that contain one or zero strings, or a list of strings?

Comment: @Samwise, both would be Ok here

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.join` to join the combination tuples you get from `itertools.combinations` into single strings:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [''.join(combo) for k in range(4) for combo in combinations('abc', k)]
['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools combinations to generate tuples that are of length x

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 1):

```
list=["a","b","c"]

new_list=[]
double_list=[]
triple_list=[]
```

I tried to solve the problem with three loops:

```
# first loop (single letters):
for i in range(len(list)):
    new_list.append(list[i])

# second loop (double letters:
i=0
while i != len(list):
    for item in list:
        double_list.append(item+list[i])
    i+=1

# third loop (tripple letters)
i=0
while i != len(list):
    for item in double_list:
        triple_list.append(item+list[i])
    i+=1

# Now combine all three lists
combined_list=new_list+double_list+triple_list
```

Since you asked for a result in which each combinations is listed as a list itself i added the following split method at the end:

```
list_list= [i.split(" ") for i in combined_list]
```